# Is it safe to check if a pointer is null, then dereference it in the same if statement?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, conditional-statements

Is the following code safe if a null pointer is passed in?

```
if(ptr && *ptr == value)
{
   //do something
}
```

Does the order of the checks matter? Does it work if I change it to this?

```
if(*ptr == value && ptr)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question title to clarify that by "valid pointer" I meant "not-null".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The former is correct and safe, the latter is not.

The built-in `&&` operator has *short-circuit semantics*, meaning that the second argument is evaluated if and only if the first one is true.

(This is not the case for *overloaded* operators.)

Comment: Thanks for the undefined behaviour pointer - I've been a practitioner for a long time and often had a lack of interest in the detail - something I am trying to remedy now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (1) is safe because of short circuiting. This is the way that the logical statement is evaluated. If the first part of the `&&` statement is false then the whole statement can never be true so it will not try to evaluate the second part.

and (2) is unsafe because it dereferences the null pointer first, which is undefined behaviour.

edit:

in reference to KerrekSBs comment below:
[Why dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793262/why-dereferencing-a-null-pointer-is-undefined-behaviour)

From the first answer in that post:

> Defining consistent behavior for dereferencing a NULL pointer would
>   require the compiler to check for NULL pointers before each
>   dereference on most CPU architectures. This  is an unacceptable
>   burdern for a language that is designed for speed.

Also there is (was historically) hardware where the memory pointed to by `NULL` (not always  `0`) is in fact addressable within the program and can be dereferenced. So because of a lack of consensus and consistency it was decided that dereferencing a null pointer would be "undefined behaviour"

Comment: (2) is not just "unsafe"; it's outright *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You might as well elaborate on the difference since you brought it up.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, `gets` is unsafe because you can't know the required buffer length, and `printf` is unsafe because you can pass wrongly typed arguments. "Unsafe" means that the correctness of the code cannot be statically verified. That's quite different to dereferencing a null pointer, which is just always bad.

Comment: Physically, null pointer is not necessarily tied to address `0`. It can be represented by any platform-specific address.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well it isn't technically "always" bad, right? The implementation may very well decide that it's a valid operation for that particular system, in which case it would be perfectly safe... it's not like the standard ***requires*** it to be undefined behavior. So I don't really see a notable difference between "unsafe" and "undefined" (though it's certainly unverifiable as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

If the pointer is invalid (or rather `NULL` as pointed out), in the first version [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) will prevent the evaluation of `*ptr == value`, so the first one is safe.

The second one will always access `*ptr`, whether it is valid or not.

Comment: `if (ptr)` cannot check for *invalid* pointers. It can only check for *null* pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was working under the assumption that "invalid" referred to "`NULL`" here. Other than that, it is rather difficult to detect pointers to nowhere in specific in C++, as you must know.

Comment: Depending on how you read the standard, the null pointer may actually be a perfectly *valid* pointer. I prefer to reserve the term "invalid pointer" for something like the address of a no longer existing object or the result of illegal pointer arithmetic. The standard has a section on "Safely-derived pointers" (3.7.4.3) for that.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the others answers about `ptr && *ptr == value` being valid, but not the other way round, the notion of valid pointer may have different meaning.

The `ptr` could be an uninitialized variable, or could be obtained (e.g. by a cast from some random `intptr_t` integer) in such a way that it does not point anywhere (e.g. a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)) but is not null.

In that case, neither order of testing works.

Some pointers can be invalid and be non-null (then testing `ptr && *ptr == value` is *undefined behavior*). There is no portable way to test them. (but you could use operating-system or processor specific tricks).