# is doing (ptr && *ptr) good way to check whether any value assigned to the ptr? mine just keep crashing

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

Im not really sure that use of ptr&&(*ptr)
At first, I was not sure about is this for checking NULL ptr or existence of assigned value.
But now after running the code below I found that in both way it just doesnt work: runtime error occurred!

Can somebody explain what nasty thing inside is happening?
GCC 5.3.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int* ptr=NULL;
//    ptr=NULL;
    int res = (ptr && *ptr);

//assigning NULL to *ptr or ptr address results in runtime error. What's happening?
//compiled with gcc.exe (GCC) 5.3.0 on windows

    printf("address: %d \n val: %d \n",ptr,*ptr);
    printf("isNullptr? ptr&& *ptr %d",res);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to get value by null pointer which is incorrect. It's like saying: give me i don't know what...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to check if a pointer is null, then dereference it in the same if statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782629/is-it-safe-to-check-if-a-pointer-is-null-then-dereference-it-in-the-same-if-sta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following line is completely ok, since short-circuiting prevents `ptr` from being dereferenced if it's equal to `NULL`.

```
int res = (ptr && *ptr);
```

But following code unconditionally dereferences it, leading to a crash.

```
int* ptr=NULL;
// ...
printf("address: %p \n val: %d \n",(void *)ptr,*ptr);
//                                             ^~~~
```

Also, please note that a proper way to print a pointer is by using `%p` instead of `%d`, and the pointer has to be casted to `void *`. I've changed your `printf()` accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("address: %d \n val: %d \n",ptr,*ptr);
```

You have trying to de-referencing a **NULL** pointer. It's **undefined behaviour**.

From **n1256** - §6.5.3.3 :

> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary *
>   operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for
>   the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the
>   end of its lifetime.

Comment: Nope, this line is ok because of short-circuiting.

Comment: Obviously not true. If ptr check failes, *ptr wont be checked.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
int * ptr = NULL

...

  printf("address: %d \n val: %d \n",ptr,*ptr);
```

results in:

1. First `ptr` is initialised using the null-pointer constant. For this the C standard guarantees that `ptr` is not pointing to any valid object. (<sup>*1</sup>)

   C11 Standard (draft) 6.3.2.3/3:

   > If a null pointer constant is converted to a
   >   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
2. Then in the second statement with doing `*ptr` gets dereferenced, that is it is tried to access what it's pointing to, which is nothing valid (see 1. above), resulting in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), from then on anything can happen, including a crash of the program.

   C11 Standard (draft) 6.5.3.2/4:

   > If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think `*ptr` (in the printf) does? It dereferences a pointer that has been assigned with `NULL` in the initialization. If you pass a NULL to function expecting non-NULL, your program invokes *undefined behavior*. The proper way to print addresses is using a `%p` specifier along with a ptr-to-void:

```
 if (ptr != NULL)
     printf ("Pointer ptr points to address %p\n", (void *)ptr);
 else
     printf ("ptr is NULL\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you have [**undefined behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It is a very [bad thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

<sup>(remember that a programming language is a specification written in some report - not a software. For [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))</sup>

In practice, you get a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). You are dereferencing -in your first call to `printf`- a (null) pointer which is always outside of your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

You should compile with all warnings & debug info e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then use a debugger (`gdb`) and a memory leak detector like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...

You need to read a lot more. Read carefully several books on programming (perhaps start with [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)), and several books on C programming. You might also want to read about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).

Comment: Int res =... Part is ok.

Comment: I did not mention it.