# I try to access the value of a null pointer in win32 application, but no access violation occurs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, null, access-violation

I wrote sample code that should cause access violation, but it does not. 
I think the exception should occur in `GetSession1()`, `GetSession2()` function for `return *m_pObj`, but it does not. Why is that?

Header file

```
class CSession
{
    public:
        CSession() {};
        ~CSession() {};
        CSession(const CSession& rhs) {};
    private:
        long m_lUSN;
};

class CTest
{
    public:
        CSession* m_pObj;
        CSession& GetSesstion1() { m_pObj = NULL; return *m_pObj; }
        CSession GetSesstion2(); { m_pObj = NULL; return *m_pObj; }
};
```

Cpp file

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CTest test;
    CSession Session2 = test.GetSesstion1();
    CSession Session3 = test.GetSesstion2();
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Dereferencing a null pointer is [undefined behaviour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLHL75H_VEM) (a more "serious" link here: [Why dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6793262/3093378)). Your program may crash, or may do whatever it wants. The C++ standard doesn't mandate to have an "access violation".

Undefined behaviour (UB) is bad, and you cannot rely on a compiler to always catch it. For example, the code below makes it clear why UB is bad:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *p = nullptr;
    int  q = *p;
    //std::cout << q;
}
```

On my machine, I get no warning whatsoever, the code compiles and runs just fine. If I un-comment the `std::cout` line, BANG, it crashes. That's because probably the compiler optimized out the dereferencing of the null pointer, however cannot optimize it out when trying to use `q`. That's what's probably happening in your code, but again, it is UB and the fact that the program runs should not give you any reassurance.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote constructors that do not do anything, so you are not actually trying to access `m_lUSN` when located at a NULL address, thus you don't get any AVs.  If you change your `CSession()` copy constructor to copy the value of `rhs.m_lUSN` to `this->m_lUSN`, or add public getter/setter methods so `_tmain()` can read/set the `m_lUSN` value, you will start seeing AVs occur from the objects returned by `GetSesstion(1|2)()`.