# Is it undefined behavior to dereference nullptr like this?

Tags: c++, nullptr

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int arr[666];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof( (static_cast<A*>(nullptr))->arr); //OK?
}
```

The code above could be run without error. Does standard say anything about such situation?

Comment: @πάντα - This is in an unevaluated operand. None of the answers in the dupe address that.

Comment: @StoryTeller Added another link with standard cites. Feel free to add better ones or reopen the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you please provide the previous linkage in the comment? I want to see that as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But I could just see one link indeed.

Comment: @bigxiao Oops, someone must have removed the original one. Wasn't me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, I would aprreciate it if you could provide that link again in the comment. I could not find that question.

Comment: @bigxiao It was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793262/why-dereferencing-a-null-pointer-is-undefined-behaviour

Comment: From what I can see, the other thread didn't have to do with member access, so there might be a usefully different answer here.  
Since C++17, apparently you should be doing this: `struct A { int arr[666]; };  
std::cout << sizeof(A().arr);`.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization.  

There is also the C way, which has been around a bit longer and, from what it looks like on cppreference, does the same thing anyway (declare a temporary object, then elide it as unused):  `std::cout << sizeof( ((struct S) { }).a )`