# Is this ->> an old operator or a typo/error?

Tags: c++, c, operators, history

In the course of my reading I came accross [WG14 Defect Report #51](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_051.html) written in 1993 (or perhaps 1893, they left off the century and millennium). In the code sample there, apparently an operator spelled `->>` is used on a pointer to a `struct`. I can't find it in any operator precedence tables I've found, so I am wondering, is or was it ever an operator, and if so, what does (or did, as the case may be) this operator do?

At first I thought it was a typo, but it is reproduced twice more in the text and another time in the code sample in the response to the question, and I have a hard time believing it just slipped past at least two C experts without being noticed, when it jumped out at a novice like me. It's also at the focal point of the code, very easy to notice, and was never corrected.

Here is the code with added indentation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
    char x[1];
};

main()
{
    struct A *p = (struct A *) malloc(sizeof(struct A) + 100);
    p->>x[5] = '?';  /* This is the key line [for both them and us] */
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this code with both a C and C++ compiler and it failed to parse in either one. Perhaps this was some operator in an early version of C that isn't used any more?

This feels suspiciously like the [What is the name of this operator: "-->"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator) question, but I don't think this is a combination of two other operators, I don't see how it can be divided up and be valid.

Comment: I have a feeling that's a typo.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes so both the questioner and the answerer copy/pasted `p->>x[5]` twice and then replied with a code sample without noticing it? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Oh, only now have I looked closely at the paper. That doesn't appear only once or twice. Either that's one heck of a copy-paste <strike>accident</strike> trainwreck or... I have no freaking idea.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I agree that it's hard to believe, but I find it easier to believe than that as recently as 1993 C had a `->>` operator since lost to historians. That Andrew Koenig is an immortal who was alive and commenting on the C standard in 1893 is somewhere between the two. Maybe he had a great-grandfather? ;-)

Comment: I am glad, it's not a [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C).

Comment: @Steve Everyone knows immortality does not exist. He's just a time traveler.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: d'oh, good call. I wonder if he reads his vanity Google alerts.

Comment: @TilmanVogel that's what I thought too, but why would they make a trigraph out of characters that the operator they're trying to graph is composed of?

Comment: @Seth, maybe it's a well-thought hoax made specifically to fool people 20 years after?

Comment: @SteveJessop yeah, 1993 isn't that long ago, but it's just very hard to call it quits here and say that it was just a cosmic typo.

Comment: Other defect reports from 1993 doesn't mention this operator at all...

Comment: <tongue-in-cheek>It's the 'struct hack' operator :) Notice you're accessing the element with index 5 of an array with a single element: which is (arguably) Undefined Behaviour. Using `->>` makes the UB more visible</tongue-in-cheek>

Comment: Simply, this code is written in 2093, so `operator->>` still not invented.

Comment: We should ask the author of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1110435/637284) as he uses `->>` :)

Comment: Note that if there is a bug, it doesn't show up in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_066.html

Comment: @Lol4t0 so it's the TARDIS operator?

Comment: We know that when Jon Skeet points to `null`, the `null` shakes in fear. So maybe _this_ is the way Jon did it back in 1993 under a pseudonym?

Comment: Why couldn't it be a typo? Have you never been so focused on a piece of code that you miss something which would seem obvious to an external viewer? `Why does this foor loop only run once? Dude it's an if, not a for loop`.

Comment: @Cicada Well it's a typo in the part of the code that they were all focused on, _and_ two people missed it, _and_ it was never corrected, _and_ there is a big comment saying `/* This is the key line */` on the very line the "typo" is on (I didn't put that there, they did), and... etc. Did you have a hard time noticing it? I couldn't help but notice it the first time I saw it. I can't lay it at the feet of bad reading this time, it's just too improbable.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yes, I noticed it right away and I *do* agree with you that it seems *very* improbable for it to be a typo. However, it seems *even more unlikely* to be something else: it behaves *just like* operator `->` and no other defect report contains `->>`, not to mention nobody has ever seen this operator before. So while it seems indeed *extremely improbable* to be a typo, it still is (IMO) *the most probable* solution.

Comment: "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth." -Arthur Conan Doyle

Comment: @Cicada if it's not another operator (which I agree is also improbable) then I would think it was not a typo but some error in the transcription (?) process after it was written.

Comment: There is a similar issue in DR 42, where the greater than sign is doubled.

Comment: Maybe someone used a very very bad Makro and a #define somewhere else in the project !?

Comment: @VaughnCato then it's some bug in the software or transcription process, if you put that down I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Looks like the <-- operator, while(0<--p)... he he

Comment: Ask the original submitter: pjp@plauger.com

Comment: @TWE It is not possible to write a macro that changes the problem tokenization in this case. (Macros can only be identifiers. You might think writing `#define p p_-##` would cause `p-` to be retokenized as `p_ --`, but `##` does not work that way.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like a problem in the transcription process.  There is a similar problem in DR 42, where the greater than sign is doubled:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/docs/rr/dr_042.html

Answer (score 23):

I learned C in 1992, and I'm 100% certain there was no such operator back then.

From the context, `p->>x[5]`, we can deduce that it appears to do exactly the same thing as the more familiar arrow operator, `->`. It is therefore likely to be a typo.

---

Alternatively, it could be an encoding issue in transcribing the code into HTML. If you look at the source to that page, you can see it's got a strange mixture of escape codes and literal `<` and `>` characters:

```
<TT><B>#include &lt;stdlib.h><BR>
```

Comment: Doubt it, see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050234/what-is-was-the-operator#comment17720959_13050234)

Comment: Updated with another possible explanation.

Comment: That is much more possible. But there is no reason to encode the > character, and there is no matching <.

Comment: In 1993, HTML-encoding scripts were quite possibly very broken.

Comment: If it is encoding issue, why `>` in `include` isn't broken?

Comment: @Lol4t0: Strictly speaking, it is. But there's no ambiguity as there's no tag for the `>` to be a part of, so your browser is going to render it verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem likely to have been a transcription error, but I think it would be useful to write out how a real C compiler would interpret this construct, anyway, just to make clear that it isn't a clever trick.  The first thing it's important to know is this sentence, from C11 §6.5.4p4 (technically, N1570; this language is unchanged since C89, although the section number was probably different; emphasis mine):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the
>   next preprocessing token is the *longest* sequence of characters that could constitute a
>   preprocessing token.

That means the six-character string `" p->>x"` must be tokenized as `p -> > x`, not `p - >> x` or `p - > > x`.  (It doesn't actually matter in this case, it would be a syntax error either way, but this rule *can* be the difference between a program parsing as intended, and not; the standard gives the example `x+++++y`, which is interpreted as `x++ ++ +y`, not as `x++ + ++y`, even though only the latter is a well-formed expression.)

The next thing to know is simply that the right-hand argument of the `->` operator must be an *identifier*, per the grammar rules for *postfix-expression* in §6.5.2.  Obviously `>` isn't an identifier, so we have a definite syntax error.